# Cannot get account name from list account id

Tags: account

Below is my code to get account name from list account id. But when I debug, result returned is null. please kindly show me my error on my code.

Code:

```java
List<PicChangeHistory__c> lstAccIds = [Select Account__c from PicChangeHistory__c];
system.system.debug('lstAccIds: '+lstAccIds);

Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for (PicChangeHistory__c s : lstAccIds) {
    accountIds.add(s.id);
}

system.debug('accountIds: '+accountIds);
         
List<Account> acts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id =: accountIds];
system.debug('acts: '+acts);
```

Comment: I've removed what appeared to be a link to an unknown third-party image host. Please use the Stack Exchange editor to include any images.

Comment: For what it's worth, the icecream site looks harmless enough (hosting screenshots from their screen recorder). Since it appears to be windows-only though, a better approach probably would've been to use alt + print screen (which will copy only the active window on a screen to your clipboard, which you can then paste into Paint, and then save).

Answer (score 2):

You're adding `PicChangeHistory__c` Ids to your `accountIds` set instead of the Account Id (i.e. `s.Account__c`).

Because a `PicChangeHistory__c` will never be an `Account` Id (`PicChangeHistory__c`'s Id will likely start with "a0", and `Account` Ids always start with "001"), your second query returns no rows.

Do note that an empty list is different from `null`. Queries never return null. They will always give you a `List<SObject>`, even if that list is empty (or an exception).

Change `s.id` to `s.Account__c` and your second query should return results.

Comment: My question is, why not just extend the original query to `SELECT Account__c, Account__r.Name FROM PicChangeHistory__c` and simply traverse the Account__r relationship to get the account name for each PicChangeHistory record? Even when there are multiple references to the same account, SOQL is smart enough to return a single Account instance, in memory, for each account.

Comment: @PhilW Point. That, or using a semi-join `SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM PicChangeHistory__c)`, or pulling it to `PicChangeHistory__c` via a formula field. I suppose that OP's example could be a simplified one.

Comment: @PhilW Point, Derek F , Thanks for your comments. I tried your solution, but I can not still get account name.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply avoid running two queries by updating the code thus:

```
List<PicChangeHistory__c> picChangeHistories =
        [SELECT Account__c, Account__r.Name FROM PicChangeHistory__c];

Set<Account> accounts = new Set<Account>();

for (PicChangeHistory__c picChangeHistory : picChangeHistories) {
    accounts.add(picChangeHistory.Account__r);
}
```

At the end of this you have a set of the unique Account records, `accounts`, related to the pic change history records, populated with the Name field (and Id, implicitly).